# execution of shell command from jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, dsl, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to execute set of commands from jenkinsfile. 
The problem is, when I try to assign the value of stdout to a variable it is not working.
I tried different combinations of double quotes and single quotes, but so far no luck.

Here I executed the script with latest version of jenkinsfile as well as old version. Putting  shell commands inside """  """ is not allowing to create new variable and giving error like client_name command does not exist.

```
String nodeLabel = env.PrimaryNode ? env.PrimaryNode : "slave1"
echo "Running on node [${nodeLabel}]"

node("${nodeLabel}"){

    sh "p4 print -q -o config.yml //c/test/gradle/hk/config.yml"
    def config = readYaml file: 'devops-config.yml'
    def out = sh (script:"client_name=${config.BasicVars.p4_client}; " +
    'echo "client name: $client_name"' +
    " cmd_output = p4 clients -e $client_name" +
    ' echo "out variable: $cmd_output"',returnStdout: true)
}
```

I want to assign the stdout from the command p4 clients -e $client_name to variable cmd_output.

But when I execute the code the error that is thrown is:

> NoSuchPropertyException: client_name is not defined at line  cmd_output = p4 clients -e $client_name

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that all the $ are interpreted by jenkins when the string is in double quotes. So the first 2 times there's no problem since the first variable comes from jenkins and the second time it's a single quote string. 
The the third variable is in a double quote string, therefore jenkins tries to replace the variable with its value but it can't find it since it's generated only when the shell script is executed.

The solution is to escape the $ in $client_name (or define client_name in an environment block).

I rewrote the block:

```
String nodeLabel = env.PrimaryNode ? env.PrimaryNode : "slave1"
echo "Running on node [${nodeLabel}]"

node("${nodeLabel}"){
    sh "p4 print -q -o config.yml //c/test/gradle/hk/config.yml"
    def config = readYaml file: 'devops-config.yml'
    def out = sh (script: """
        client_name=${config.BasicVars.p4_client}
        echo "client name: \$client_name"
        cmd_output = p4 clients -e \$client_name
        echo "out variable: \$cmd_output"
    """, returnStdout: true)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It was really helpful. Finally resolved it with your inputs.